# Spring Boot Project with Maven, can't Import WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security, import

Trying to do User Authentication for a Spring Boot project using Maven but it wont import:

org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

It says:

Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'

Here is my pom.xml file can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.5
 

com.ggs
AT6
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
AT6
AT6

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-security


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.thymeleaf.extras
thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter was removed in Spring-boot 3.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: It is SecurityFilterChain.

Comment: you are following an outdated tutorial, if you are to learn spring security i recommend you read the official documentation on their webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do something wrong.

It's just that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. I advise you to follow this spring guide to define your own security configuration without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: It is not only deprecated but really removed now. Code need to be migrated with SecurityFilterChain.